# Implementing authentication and authorization in clean architecture with C#

Tags: c#, authentication, authorization, clean-architecture

In ASP.NET Core, we can use the `[Authorize]` attribute on our methods in controllers. It works fine for both authentication and authorization.

But while using clean architecture, we can't do it. Authentication and authorization belongs to the application layer. (or am I wrong?)

The problem is that every time I want to authenticate or authorize something, I need to do it manually in code. It doesn't look good.

So I thought there must be better solution. I know that I could use `MediatR` and the pipelines, but I don't use it. Instead, I have simple interface `IRequestHandler<TRequest, TResult>` with `HandleAsync` method.

How could I perform authentication or authorization on every call to `HandleAsync` from classes that inherits from `IRequestHandler` or directly from it? How can I cancel processing of `HandleAsync` method if the authentication/authorization fails and return appropriate result (by appropriate I mean compatible with `TResult` defined in `IRequestHandler`)?

Comment: This sentence `How could I perform authentication or authorization on every call to HandleAsync from classes that inherits from IRequestHandler or directly from it` describes the pipeline's purpose. Their purpose is to run on every request and alter or modify the flow.

Comment: @Eldar how can I have pipeline like this? Is there any ready to use solution except `MediatR`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are mixed up about what the UI layer is. All the controllers, filters, middleware, views and view models are the UI layer.

Given that Auth in ASP.NET Core is handled by filters and middleware, this means that the Auth is in the UI layer.

There is nothing wrong with marking your methods/controllers with the attributes as that is exactly what they are for.

Check this for more info (my source): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/common-web-application-architectures#organizing-code-in-clean-architecture

Comment: So Application layer doesn't know about authentication and authorization?

Comment: No. It does not need to. You provide Application layer services to the UI layer. The UI layer   transfers the user interaction by authorizing the user and passing it on to the application layer. Auth is always in the UI layer because you are authorizing that interface. Once inside the app domain there is no need to re-auth unless you break out into another app domain. If you need to separate Read/Write consider two interfaces.